# Inudced drag distribution at eliptic and rectangular wing?

Tags: aerodynamics

I am intersted in induced drag distribution at recnatugular and eliptic wing? It would be even better if graph show downwash distribution, lift distribution and stall behaviour for more wing shapes..

Why here lift and Cl distiribution are not the same?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Guys, please don't downvote without explaining why. It's so very, very rude. Downvoters: are you upset about the content? About the typos? About something else?

Answer (score 1):

The local lift, usually lowercase $l$ is integrated to form the total lift $L$.

$L=\int_{-b/2}^{b/2} l\,dy$

Just as $L=C_L\, q\, S_{ref}$, $l=c_l\,q\,c$ where $c_l$ (note lower case) is used for 2D and it is multiplied by the local chord.

You might notice that

$S=\int_{-b/2}^{b/2} c\, dy$

So, in the figure above, the chart labeled $C_L$ should have been labeled $c_l$ and the chart labeled 'Lift' should have been labeled $l$.  This looks like a chart that may have been correct in its original form, but has been re-made so many times that over time someone didn't understand the importance of lower-case capitalization on those labels.

The reason the $c_l$ and $l$ charts do not look the same is because the chord of those wings varies.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145812/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-mcdonald-inudced-drag-distribution-at-eliptic-and-re); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.